# How to share Google Keep labels with others?

Tags: google-keep

I have multiple Google Keep labels and I would like to share them with other users. I know you can share a single note but I would like to share an entire Label.

Is this possible? And if yes, how can I do it?

Comment: This still doesn't seem possible, it seems you have to share each note individually

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to share multiple notes directly within Google Keep.

It is however possible to **export multiple notes into one Google Doc file**, where they then can be shared.

To share all notes of one label via Google Docs, follow these steps:

1. Select the label you want to share
2. Select all notes (cmd-a)
3. Choose "More" (the three vertical dots at the top right of the screen) and "Copy to Google Docs"
4. Open the Doc in Google Docs (a link should have appeared at the bottom left in Google Keep)
5. Choose "Share" at the top right of the screen